# Formula update no longer working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the same formula update problem as others posted on this site.

I have a formula in `B20`: `=SUM(B1+B20)`. I'm trying to enter dollar amount in `B1` and updating the dollar amount in `B20`, thus increasing the `B20` amount as time goes by. The formula is set to 'automatic' but the update does not work. I have tried the fixes as stated and they don't work.

This was not a problem as of last week.  All of a sudden it popped up right after the announcement from Microsoft, that it wasn't supporting XP any more.

I keep getting the 'circulation' error and the formulas no longer work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What is in the cell of B1 and of B20?

Comment: Both contain currency.  B1   $4.00    B20   $7.95 for example.  B20 will increase as time goes by and B1 will be zeroed out after each use.

Comment: Updated manually or by a macro? I assume the cell doesn't contain the dollar symbol and that is just the format?

Comment: Why do you think Microsoft not supporting XP has anything to do with it, and why do you think they only announced it last week?

Comment: Here is the formula for B20: =SUM(B02+B20)  The format is 'currency' and looks like this: $0,000.00. B2 format is 'currency' and looks like this: $0,000.00

Comment: Microsoft announced the end of Windows XP over a year ago and is not due to take affect for another two weeks. This is not your issue here. Just for eliminating potential issues sake. You issue appears to be trying to update a cell you have included in your formula. In this case remove B20 from your formula.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, you are using this code (although your original post says B1, I'll keep it with B2)

[image]

You say you are using

```
=SUM(B2+B20)
```

The problem you have is, this formula is in `B20`.

Just use

```
=B2
```

Comment: That doesn't work.   I key in a figure in B2 and I loose the formula. I want to use B2 as a data entry cell and I want to enter currency.  By doing this I want to UPDATE B20 and the amount that is in there. Havn't I explained this before?

Comment: @RobertBurns You said the formula is in B20 though? Please explain how do you lose the formula?

Comment: Look Dave, I believe I explained this the best I can and I've tried your suggestion, ie switch the formula to B2 which didn't work.  Maybe someone else can answer my simple question.

Comment: @RobertBurns The people here are helping you for free. Don't be a jerk when you don't get the answer you want.

Comment: That's just it, I'm getting no answer from Dave.  I tell him his response didn't work and he replies "You said the formula is in B20 though?".  It gets a bit frustrating when you've been racking your brain out for days and ask for assistance and the person who is 'trying' to help isn't listening to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

It's call a `circular reference` because your formula contains a reference to the cell the formula resides in.

> When a formula refers back to its own cell, either directly or
>   indirectly, it is called a circular reference. Microsoft Excel cannot
>   automatically calculate all open workbooks when one of them contains a
>   circular reference.

To resolve this you will need to either [allow or correct a circular reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/allow-or-correct-a-circular-reference-HP005200285.aspx).

You can not type a dollar amount in `B20` without it overwriting the formula itself. The easiest thing to do would be to place the formula in another cell, say `C20` so it can calculate properly.

Comment: Problem solved.  I got rid of the formulas.

Comment: That will most definitely resolve the error you were getting. :-)